# In Minecraft 1.12.2, what is the command to destroy a specific named item that is on the ground?

Tags: minecraft

In Minecraft version 1.12.2 I need to use a command to destroy a specific named item that has been dropped on the ground. What would this command be?
I tried /kill @e[type=dirt]' and got the error 'Selector '@e[type=dirt]' found nothing'.

Comment: This should be answered on gaming.stackexhange.com.

Answer (score 1):

The command is `/kill @e[type=item]`.
That will delete EVERY dropped item on the ground currently.

An example of clearing a specific item would be `/kill @e[type=dirt]`  that will delete ALL DIRT blocks that are DROPPED. The process is similar on Bedrock Edition of Minecraft.

Comment: It says 'Selector '@e[type=dirt]' found nothing